# how to make the condition for the display of an image using laravel?

Tags: laravel

i did the loop to display images in blade, in my case it display empty image if image does not exist, then i want when the image does not exist it will display image whose name is `not-found.jpg` and whose root is `img/not-found.jpg`, if not it will display normal image.

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$annonce->image) }}" class="img-responsive" style="width: 240px;height: 240px" />
```

Comment: Why do you have references in your database to files that don't exist?

Comment: @ceejayoz possible image to be deleted, or moved to wrong place

Comment: Well, don't delete/move images in a way that doesn't also update the database, then. Make those functions part of your app, rather than manually breaking things via FTP.

Comment: @ceejayoz if there is a client that does not want to insert image, then I want the site to display image `not-found.jpg`

Comment: Then you should leave `image` null, and handle that. `@if($annonce->image) // show image @else // show something else`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<img src="{{ !empty($annonce->image) ? asset('storage/'.$annonce->image) : asset('/img/not-found.jpg') }}" class="img-responsive" style="width: 240px;height: 240px" />
```